# Conditional coloring of the selected element in a treeview control

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a TreeView control, which contains multiple elements, nodes. Is there a way to change the selected item's foreground color **or** background color (by default blue background with white foreground is applied to the selected element) based on some condition. In my case, I will retrieve an object and check its 'NeedSync' property. If it's value is true, I'd want the element to
have, for example, a green background. If it's false, I'd like the background to be red.

I looked at other similar threads, but the requirement there are to change the color of the unselected elements using the treeview's _DrawItem method. In WPF this should be possible by changing the controls style and specifying triggers.

What about here, in windows forms?

EDIT: **I only have to change the font color or the backcolor of the selected element, everything else should stay the same**. Is there a way to get the default style source code for the selected node? Implementing the drawNode method removes the collapsable icon, margins, some other things.

Comment: Yes, you have to use the DrawNode method.  Set the DrawMode property to  OwnerDrawText.

Comment: Yes you will need to code the `DrawNode` event. There you can check for `e.State.HasFlag(TreeNodeStates.Selected)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As said in the comments, you will need to change the `DrawMode` property to `OwnerDrawText` and then have something like this in the `DrawNode` event:

```
private void treeView1_DrawNode(object sender, DrawTreeNodeEventArgs e) 
{
   Brush foreColour;
   Brush backColour;
   if (e.Node.IsSelected) 
   {
      if (e.Node.Text == "Node1") 
      {
          // Special highlight colouring 
          foreColour = Brushes.Yellow;
          backColour = Brushes.Red;
      }
      else 
      {
          // Default highlight colouring 
          foreColour = SystemBrushes.HighlightText;
          backColour = SystemBrushes.Highlight;
      }
   }
   else {
      if (e.Node.Text == "Node1") 
      {
         // Special colouring 
         foreColour = Brushes.Red;
         backColour = Brushes.Yellow;
      }
      else 
      {
         // Default colouring 
         foreColour = SystemBrushes.WindowText;
         backColour = SystemBrushes.Window;
      }
   }
   e.Graphics.FillRectangle(backColour, e.Bounds);
   e.Graphics.DrawString(e.Node.Text, treeView1.Font, foreColour, e.Bounds);
}
```

(I don't know what criteria you want to use, so I added `e.Node.Text == "Node1"` as an example.)

NB: You may want to add additional (but similar) logic to fade the colours if the treeview loses focus.